# Newb looking for project advice

Tags: modeling

I am working on a tutorial of a rocket, it is going well but I would like to modify it. I know that there are a lot of ways to approach it but I am looking for the best way to make the inside of the rocket hollow so eventually you will be able to see something in the window.

If I start by making a hollow cube will it remain hollow even after I put it through many modifications and scalings?[image]

Boolians?

Comment: I understand your description. I think part of my confusion is that I'm having a problem with the boolean modifier. I believe I'm applying it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The thing **hollow** is kind of uncertain naming. Blender use *surface based model* for manipulate, which only surfaces are defined in your scene. So yes, every thing you see in your model can be a hollow thing by its model properties.

Maybe you are asking a **closed surface** behavior after manipulating? In that case, making a **shell** for the rocket will be a better idea. Using **Solidify Modifier** can make the object getting a thickness shell surface. So when you look inside the rocket through the tiny window, the surface will not be the wrong direction (backface).

But when the backface is not a consideration. You don't need to solidify it if the view is OK with backface as below:

[image: hollow]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to care if your shape is hollow or not, just model your rocket, if the shape is closed it will be considered as full, but at any moment you can dig a hole and it will appear hollow, then if you want to give it back thickness you can easily do it: extrude the whole mesh and scale down, or simply use a modifier *Solidify* and apply at the end.

[image]

Comment: I understand your description. I think part of my confusion is that I'm having a problem with the boolean modifier. I believe I'm applying it correctly.   Unfortunately, I'm not able to add a jpeg to comments but when I add a boolean modifier to 2 intersecting meshes a hole (difference0 is not cut.

Comment: Actually I didn't boolean, I made a hole, extrude the hole and scaled down, then use the W > LoopTools > Circle (LoopTools needs to be activated)

Comment: even without LoopTools you can use the ["to sphere"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/to_sphere.html) function

Comment: yes, as Cegaton says, use Circle tool or shift alt S to transform to circle